# Navegação entre telas flutter

Tags: mobile, flutter, dart

tenho o seguinte código, que é chamado na main.dart para exibir, e gostaria de fazer a navegação para outra tela(classe), porem quando uso rotas, quando chamo o elemento `navigator`, ele da erro no `context` do *Widget* `navigator` e não faz a navegação entre as paginas, porque ao invés de ser *Widget* `build(BuildContext context) {}`,ele é, Widget `_buildPageContent() {}` apenas, e da erro no `context` do `navigator`.

Gostaria de saber como chamar a outra tela usando o botão login definido no código?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'mainview.dart';

class LoginView extends StatelessWidget {
  static final String path = "lib/loginview.dart";


  Widget _buildPageContent() {
    return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        color: Colors.grey.shade800,
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  height: 50,
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 200,
                ),
                Image.asset('lib/img/prospentlogov1.png', width: 150,),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 50,
                ),
                ListTile(
                    title: TextField(
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Endereço de E-mail",
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      icon: Icon(Icons.email, color: Colors.white30)),
                )),
                Divider(
                  color: Colors.cyan,
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: TextField(
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Senha:",
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.lock,
                          color: Colors.white30,
                        )),
                  ),
                ),
                Divider(
                  color: Colors.cyan,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: () async {

                        },
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        child: Text(
                          'Login',
                          style:
                              TextStyle(color: Colors.white70, fontSize: 16.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 40,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Esqueceu sua senha?',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.lightGreen),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _buildPageContent(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Uma dica: Não é uma boa prática colocar Widgets para serem retornados por métodos. Dê preferência por criar um outro Widget com as coisas que necessita e depois chamá-lo onde deseja.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica amigo. Sou iniciante em dev mobile, e ainda estou me adaptando ao flutter. Obrigado pela sua dica, vou tentar refazer deste modo tambem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na sua função `_buildPageContent()` coloque o parâmetro de contexto, então quando vc for chamar ela no body do Scaffold passe o `context`. Ex:

```dart
  Widget _buildPageContent(BuildContext context) {...seucodigo...}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _buildPageContent(context),
    );
  }
```

Dessa forma, quando vc chamar o navigator, vc terá acesso ao context

Comment: Obrigado amigo, ajudou muito!! sou iniciante em dev mobile e estou tendo algumas dificuldades. Mas obrigado pela força